# How to work with Windows Task Scheduler to get last run date using Java

Tags: java, mysql, spring, oracle, scheduled-tasks

I want to send a report of Registered users on the website every week from users' table in MySQL/Oracle database. For this, I have created a Java program that fetches registered users within a week and saves it in an excel file and sends it in a mail. I'm scheduling this task with Windows Task Scheduler to run every week. I want to get the last run time of that scheduler and next run time to add in the SQL query.

My SQL query is as below.

```
SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE TRUNC(USER_CREATION_DATE) BETWEEN 'FROMDATE' AND 'TODATE';
```

`FROM_DATE` and `TO_DATE` will be the variables.

Is there are any better approach to get `FROM_DATE` and `TO_DATE` when the scheduler runs on the first day of the week (i.e Sunday), which means I want last Sunday as `FROM_DATE` and Saturday as `TO_DATE` in Java.

Please help me to get `FROM_DATE` and `TO_DATE` of last week.

Comment: Question is whether you want the time of the last run, or you want to just go 7 days ago. You can add days to the current date for the latter. For the former, you could probably save it in a special table in the database. One row, update every time you start a job.

Comment: Hey Santosh, have you considered making java write a text data file with the last run date?

Comment: No i will try to write file